# While Compiling gobject-introspection-1.44.0 getting list of errors

Tags: c++, linux, gtk, gobject-introspection

For building GTK gobject-introspection-1.44.0 is required, It is configured without error but in `make` I'm getting a list of errors.

```
CC       _giscanner_la-giscannermodule.lo
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:42:1: warning: return type defaults to 'int' [-Wreturn-type]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:42:1: warning: no previous prototype for 'DL_EXPORT' [-Wmissing-prototypes]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c: In function 'DL_EXPORT':
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:42:17: error: expected declaration specifiers before 'init_giscanner'
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:74:3: error: storage class specified for parameter 'PyGISourceType'
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:76:19: error: storage class specified for parameter 'pygi_source_type_new'
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:81:3: error: storage class specified for parameter 'PyGISourceSymbol'
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:86:3: error: storage class specified for parameter 'PyGISourceScanner'
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:88:1: error: storage class specified for parameter '_PyGISourceSymbol_methods'
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:88:1: error: parameter 'PyGISourceSymbol_Type' is initialized
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:88:1: warning: missing braces around initializer [-Wmissing-braces]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:88:1: warning: (near initialization for 'PyGISourceSymbol_Type.ob_base.ob_base') [-Wmissing-braces]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:88:1: warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:88:1: warning: (near initialization for 'PyGISourceSymbol_Type.tp_basicsize') [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:88:1: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:88:1: warning: (near initialization for 'PyGISourceSymbol_Type.tp_doc') [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:89:1: error: storage class specified for parameter '_PyGISourceType_methods'
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:89:1: error: parameter 'PyGISourceType_Type' is initialized
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:89:1: warning: missing braces around initializer [-Wmissing-braces]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:89:1: warning: (near initialization for 'PyGISourceType_Type.ob_base.ob_base') [-Wmissing-braces]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:89:1: warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:89:1: warning: (near initialization for 'PyGISourceType_Type.tp_basicsize') [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:89:1: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:89:1: warning: (near initialization for 'PyGISourceType_Type.tp_doc') [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:90:1: error: storage class specified for parameter '_PyGISourceScanner_methods'
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:90:1: error: parameter 'PyGISourceScanner_Type' is initialized
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:90:1: warning: missing braces around initializer [-Wmissing-braces]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:90:1: warning: (near initialization for 'PyGISourceScanner_Type.ob_base.ob_base') [-Wmissing-braces]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:90:1: warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:90:1: warning: (near initialization for 'PyGISourceScanner_Type.tp_basicsize') [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:90:1: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:90:1: warning: (near initialization for 'PyGISourceScanner_Type.tp_doc') [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:97:1: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '{' token
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:113:18: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'PyGISourceSymbol'
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:120:18: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'PyGISourceSymbol'
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:127:21: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'PyGISourceSymbol'
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:134:19: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'PyGISourceSymbol'
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:148:23: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'PyGISourceSymbol'
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:155:23: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'PyGISourceSymbol'
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:171:26: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'PyGISourceSymbol'
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:183:26: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'PyGISourceSymbol'
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:196:27: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'PyGISourceSymbol'
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:209:29: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'PyGISourceSymbol'
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:221:26: error: storage class specified for parameter '_PyGISourceSymbol_getsets'
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:221:1: error: parameter '_PyGISourceSymbol_getsets' is initialized
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:223:3: warning: braces around scalar initializer [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:223:3: warning: (near initialization for '_PyGISourceSymbol_getsets') [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:223:3: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:223:3: warning: (near initialization for '_PyGISourceSymbol_getsets') [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:223:21: error: 'symbol_get_type' undeclared (first use in this function)
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:223:21: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:223:3: warning: excess elements in scalar initializer [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:223:3: warning: (near initialization for '_PyGISourceSymbol_getsets') [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:223:3: warning: excess elements in scalar initializer [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:223:3: warning: (near initialization for '_PyGISourceSymbol_getsets') [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:223:3: warning: excess elements in scalar initializer [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:223:3: warning: (near initialization for '_PyGISourceSymbol_getsets') [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:225:3: warning: braces around scalar initializer [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:225:3: warning: (near initialization for '_PyGISourceSymbol_getsets') [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:225:3: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:225:3: warning: (near initialization for '_PyGISourceSymbol_getsets') [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:225:22: error: 'symbol_get_ident' undeclared (first use in this function)
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:225:3: warning: excess elements in scalar initializer [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:225:3: warning: (near initialization for '_PyGISourceSymbol_getsets') [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:225:3: warning: excess elements in scalar initializer [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:225:3: warning: (near initialization for '_PyGISourceSymbol_getsets') [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:225:3: warning: excess elements in scalar initializer [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:225:3: warning: (near initialization for '_PyGISourceSymbol_getsets') [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:225:3: warning: excess elements in scalar initializer [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:225:3: warning: (near initialization for '_PyGISourceSymbol_getsets') [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:342:3: warning: (near initialization for '_PyGISourceType_getsets') [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:342:3: warning: excess elements in scalar initializer [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:342:3: warning: (near initialization for '_PyGISourceType_getsets') [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:342:3: warning: excess elements in scalar initializer [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:342:3: warning: (near initialization for '_PyGISourceType_getsets') [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:343:3: warning: braces around scalar initializer [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:343:3: warning: (near initialization for '_PyGISourceType_getsets') [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:343:3: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:343:3: warning: (near initialization for '_PyGISourceType_getsets') [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:343:35: error: 'type_get_function_specifier' undeclared (first use in this function)
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:343:3: warning: excess elements in scalar initializer [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:343:3: warning: (near initialization for '_PyGISourceType_getsets') [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:343:3: warning: excess elements in scalar initializer [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:343:3: warning: (near initialization for '_PyGISourceType_getsets') [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:343:3: warning: excess elements in scalar initializer [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:343:3: warning: (near initialization for '_PyGISourceType_getsets') [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:343:3: warning: excess elements in scalar initializer [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:343:3: warning: (near initialization for '_PyGISourceType_getsets') [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:344:3: warning: braces around scalar initializer [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:344:3: warning: (near initialization for '_PyGISourceType_getsets') [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:344:3: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:344:3: warning: (near initialization for '_PyGISourceType_getsets') [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:344:21: error: 'type_get_name' undeclared (first use in this function)
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:344:3: warning: excess elements in scalar initializer [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:344:3: warning: (near initialization for '_PyGISourceType_getsets') [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:344:3: warning: excess elements in scalar initializer [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:344:3: warning: (near initialization for '_PyGISourceType_getsets') [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:344:3: warning: excess elements in scalar initializer [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:344:3: warning: (near initialization for '_PyGISourceType_getsets') [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:344:3: warning: excess elements in scalar initializer [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:344:3: warning: (near initialization for '_PyGISourceType_getsets') [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:345:3: warning: excess elements in scalar initializer [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:345:3: warning: (near initialization for '_PyGISourceType_getsets') [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:346:3: warning: braces around scalar initializer [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:346:3: warning: (near initialization for '_PyGISourceType_getsets') [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:346:3: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:346:3: warning: (near initialization for '_PyGISourceType_getsets') [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:346:27: error: 'type_get_child_list' undeclared (first use in this function)
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:346:3: warning: excess elements in scalar initializer [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:346:3: warning: (near initialization for '_PyGISourceType_getsets') [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:346:3: warning: excess elements in scalar initializer [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:346:3: warning: (near initialization for '_PyGISourceType_getsets') [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:346:3: warning: excess elements in scalar initializer [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:346:3: warning: (near initialization for '_PyGISourceType_getsets') [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:346:3: warning: excess elements in scalar initializer [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:346:3: warning: (near initialization for '_PyGISourceType_getsets') [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:347:3: warning: braces around scalar initializer [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:347:3: warning: (near initialization for '_PyGISourceType_getsets') [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:347:3: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:347:3: warning: (near initialization for '_PyGISourceType_getsets') [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:347:28: error: 'type_get_is_bitfield' undeclared (first use in this function)
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:347:3: warning: excess elements in scalar initializer [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:347:3: warning: (near initialization for '_PyGISourceType_getsets') [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:347:3: warning: excess elements in scalar initializer [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:347:3: warning: (near initialization for '_PyGISourceType_getsets') [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:347:3: warning: excess elements in scalar initializer [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:347:3: warning: (near initialization for '_PyGISourceType_getsets') [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:347:3: warning: excess elements in scalar initializer [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:347:3: warning: (near initialization for '_PyGISourceType_getsets') [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:348:3: warning: braces around scalar initializer [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:348:3: warning: (near initialization for '_PyGISourceType_getsets') [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:348:3: warning: excess elements in scalar initializer [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:348:3: warning: (near initialization for '_PyGISourceType_getsets') [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:356:27: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'PyGISourceScanner'
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:369:38: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'PyGISourceScanner'
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:386:35: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'PyGISourceScanner'
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:421:33: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'PyGISourceScanner'
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:525:35: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'PyGISourceScanner'
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:548:37: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'PyGISourceScanner'
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:612:3: warning: excess elements in scalar initializer [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:612:3: warning: (near initialization for '_PyGISourceScanner_methods') [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:613:3: warning: braces around scalar initializer [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:613:3: warning: (near initialization for '_PyGISourceScanner_methods') [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:613:3: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:613:3: warning: (near initialization for '_PyGISourceScanner_methods') [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:613:35: error: 'pygi_source_scanner_lex_filename' undeclared (first use in this function)
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:613:3: warning: excess elements in scalar initializer [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:613:3: warning: (near initialization for '_PyGISourceScanner_methods') [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:613:3: warning: excess elements in scalar initializer [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:613:3: warning: (near initialization for '_PyGISourceScanner_methods') [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:613:3: warning: excess elements in scalar initializer [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:613:3: warning: (near initialization for '_PyGISourceScanner_methods') [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:614:3: warning: braces around scalar initializer [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:614:3: warning: (near initialization for '_PyGISourceScanner_methods') [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:614:3: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:614:3: warning: (near initialization for '_PyGISourceScanner_methods') [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:614:37: error: 'pygi_source_scanner_set_macro_scan' undeclared (first use in this function)
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:614:3: warning: excess elements in scalar initializer [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:614:3: warning: (near initialization for '_PyGISourceScanner_methods') [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:614:3: warning: excess elements in scalar initializer [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:614:3: warning: (near initialization for '_PyGISourceScanner_methods') [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:614:3: warning: excess elements in scalar initializer [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:614:3: warning: (near initialization for '_PyGISourceScanner_methods') [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:615:3: warning: braces around scalar initializer [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:615:3: warning: (near initialization for '_PyGISourceScanner_methods') [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:615:3: warning: excess elements in scalar initializer [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:615:3: warning: (near initialization for '_PyGISourceScanner_methods') [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:615:3: warning: excess elements in scalar initializer [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:615:3: warning: (near initialization for '_PyGISourceScanner_methods') [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:615:3: warning: excess elements in scalar initializer [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:615:3: warning: (near initialization for '_PyGISourceScanner_methods') [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:621:1: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '{' token
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:671:1: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '{' token
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:770:26: error: storage class specified for parameter 'pyscanner_functions'
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:770:1: error: parameter 'pyscanner_functions' is initialized
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:771:3: warning: braces around scalar initializer [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:771:3: warning: (near initialization for 'pyscanner_functions') [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:771:3: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:771:3: warning: (near initialization for 'pyscanner_functions') [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:772:19: error: 'pygi_collect_attributes' undeclared (first use in this function)
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:772:5: warning: excess elements in scalar initializer [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:772:5: warning: (near initialization for 'pyscanner_functions') [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:772:5: warning: excess elements in scalar initializer [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:772:5: warning: (near initialization for 'pyscanner_functions') [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:773:3: warning: braces around scalar initializer [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:773:3: warning: (near initialization for 'pyscanner_functions') [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:773:3: warning: excess elements in scalar initializer [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:773:3: warning: (near initialization for 'pyscanner_functions') [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:773:3: warning: excess elements in scalar initializer [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:773:3: warning: (near initialization for 'pyscanner_functions') [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:773:3: warning: excess elements in scalar initializer [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:773:3: warning: (near initialization for 'pyscanner_functions') [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:773:3: warning: excess elements in scalar initializer [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:773:3: warning: (near initialization for 'pyscanner_functions') [enabled by default]
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:776:1: error: expected declaration specifiers before 'DL_EXPORT'
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:42:1: error: old-style parameter declarations in prototyped function definition
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:799:1: error: expected '{' at end of input
giscanner/giscannermodule.c:799:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
make[2]: *** [_giscanner_la-giscannermodule.lo] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/vishal/AVM/GTK+/dependencies/gobject-introspection-1.44.0'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/vishal/AVM/GTK+/dependencies/gobject-introspection-1.44.0'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Any help

Comment: This is not a great question. In any case, you're using the wrong Python version. I guess you're on Arch, which replaced Python with Python3.

Comment: yes you were right. I installed Python 2.7.9 instead of 3.* and it worked. Thanks a lott!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by changing the Python version as told by https://stackoverflow.com/users/771066/ebassi.

Just use old version of Python 2.7.* any.

Answer (score 2):

GObject Introspection [doesn't support Python 3](https://developer.gnome.org/gi/stable/gi-building.html) yet. DL_EXPORT is defined in Python.h for Python 2, but not Python 3, so the compiler doesn't know what to do with it.

I ran into this same issue trying to compile GTK+3 in the Anaconda 3.4 distribution. Strangely, [this](http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html) suggests that it will work.

Answer (score -1):

Seems like your compiler (CC) does not support the DL_EXPORT macro. You should most likely be using gcc to compile the gtk+ toolchain. That will save you a lot of trouble, at least until you are very familiar with all the build dependencies and processes.

Comment: I'm using gcc latest version.